# Convert the output of shrinkwrap modifier into a mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm a newbie to Blender, and this is the thing I'm trying to accomplish. I've got a bezier curve in 3D space and a grid. I want to show the projection of the curve onto the grid, so I use the shrinkwrap modifier on the curve to project on the grid. So far, I managed to get all this working ok.

Now I would like the projection to appear in a render of the scene, so I think I need the output of the shrinkwrap to be a mesh (correct me if I'm wrong!). **How do I do this?** I'm looking for a python blender api way of accomplishing this, but any hint on how to get me started would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Do you mean apply the modifier?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm sorry, maybe I expressed myself wrong, I'm just a newbie in blender (and english is not my first language). I actually apply the modifier and I get the projection (and the geometry checks out from what I can see). BUT the think is that now I want the resulting curve (the projection onto the grid) to appear in a render. So **I guess** I need it to be a mesh, right? If that's the case, my question is: how to achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify the text there. Some users that might be able to help you do not read comments. Add images that show what you want to do.

Comment: Curves can be converted to a mesh, in the menu select Object > Convert to > Mesh.

Comment: For the curve to appear in a render, it has to have a thickness. At its simplest, that means just giving the curve a native Bevel in its Data tab > Geometry panel. If you like, you can convert that to a mesh.